# Why is normal force at a different location than its action forces (ie, seesaw)?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity

[image]

It seems very counterintuitive that the forces at the two ends also constitute the normal force at the pivot point.

Does this principle apply even if the plank is tilted?

(It would be good someone can explain this with mathematics)

Comment: Forces act on points of contact. The weight of the people in the seesaw acts on where they're sat down, and the normal to the seesaw acts where it touches the only object upon which it could exert a force... in your drawing, the cone what works as a handle.

Comment: "Normal" is a mathematical synonym for "perpendicular".  The normal force is always perpendicular to the surface at the point of contact.   So the normal force does change with tilt.